# Ruby Integer Assignments - Adapting Ruby Assignments to C Type Languages

Tags: c#, ruby, int

All,

I am trying to adapt some Ruby code to work in C# but C# does not offer the same available assignment syntax like Ruby

Here is some Ruby code that I am trying to Adapt:

```
    x, x1 = x1, x-q*x1
    y, y1 = y1, y-q*y1
    a, b  =  b, a-q*b
```

So, I took it and did this, but I get different results than above:

```
    x = x1
    x1 = x-q*x1
    y = y1
    y1 = y-q*y1
    a = b
    b  = a-q*b
```

How is Ruby evaluating the assignments? Why is it when I beak out the multiple assignments into singular assignments the results are different?

Comment: You need to use some temp variables.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why are temp vars needed? Thanks

Comment: Can you include a working example? To see the different results? What types are the variables in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby first evaluates each expression on the RHS, then assigns them to the repsective LHS variables.

Here's (basically) how Ruby evaluates the third line `a, b  =  b, a-q*b`:

```
temp1 = b
temp2 = a-q*b
a = temp1
b = temp2
```

An example with `a = 5`, `b = 7`, and `q = 10`:

```
a, b = (7), (5 - 10*7)
```

yields

```
a == 7
b == -65
```

As you can see, no value `a` or `b` is changed from its initial value before a RHS expression using it is evaluated.

Contrast with what's going on in your C# code:

```
a = b      // a is changed BEFORE evaluating the value
           //   that will be put into b
b = a-q*b  // The value of a has already been changed:
           //   this is now the same as b = b-q*b, which is not intended
```

Example results using same values as above:

```
a == 7
b == 7 - 10*7 == -63  // Not what we want...
```

To get the correct result, use the multi-line assignment with temp variables at the top of this answer:

```
temp1 = b       // 7
temp2 = a-q*b   // 5 - 10*7 == -65
a = temp1       // 7
b = temp2       // -65
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby evaluates the right side of the assignment before reassigning the variables. To make this more explicit, it is doing something like this:

```
new_x, new_x1 = old_x1, old_x-q*old_x1
```

This results in:

```
new_x = old_x1
new_x1 = old_x-q*old_x1
```

but what you are doing is this:

```
new_x = old_x1
new_x1 = new_x-q*old_x1 (= old_x1 - q * old_x1 = (1 - q) * old_x1)
```

Hence the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

The line `x, x1 = x1, x-q*x1` means that both x and x1 will get assigned basically at the same time, but your C# variant does not take that into consideration. In your c# code x will be assigned before x1 and thus x1 will get assigned `x1-q*x1` instead of `x-q*x1` because x is already assigned to be x1 at this time.

A possible and generic C# solution is

```
tempX = x1
tempX1 = x-q*x1
x = tempX
x1 = tempX1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in the assignment

```
x, x1 = x1, x-q*x1
```

Ruby evaluates *both* expressions on the right-hand-side before performing either of the assignments. But if you write

```
x = x1
x1 = x-q*x1
```

then because the first statement modifies the value of `x`, the value of the expression `x-q*x1` has also changed.

You need to use a temporary variable, like this

```
newx = x1
x1 = x-q*x1
x = newx
```

to avoid the effects of evaluating the expressions too early.